# Hyperledger Fabric: Is it possible to save milions of registers of locations without saturate the blockchain?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

The title practically says everything.

In a near future I'm going to implement a real-time tracking system using possibly, a blockchain, and for certain reasons Hyperledger Fabric seems to be the chosen technology. After the information is recorded, it should be accessible in a map in a web application.

So the question is: If we save every one or two minutes the location of a truck to the blockchain using gps, it will hurt the general performance of the blockchain in a near future? (milions and milions of registers)

In the end I have to decide if I should save this information in the blockchain or, knowing that it would cause some serious issues, leave that information out of it and use an hybrid system with a classic database for that and a blockchain for other functionalities that won't cause performance issues.

Thanks.

Comment: why do you need hyperledger for this?

Comment: Because I 'need' hyperledger for other issues, that's just one use case among others that use a blockchain (different actors, no trust between them, etc...), so I need to know if I should put this information in the blockchain or not, and if not...why I shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

There is no storage limitation on the Fabric Ledger other than the disk space. The current value of a key (say, the latest position of the truck)can be read via Fabric query which are saved in the world state for quick retrieval. There is also mechanism to look up the history of a key quickly via the historyDB that Fabric maintains.

Comment: But it will work fine when you have like 50 trucks sending their location continously? (besides other possible transactions). I'm a little afraid after some other people told me it's a bad idea.